# Web components in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I've created a little web component without any frameworks. This is my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="clock.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
    <clock-digital></clock-digital>
    <script>
        console.log(document.querySelector('clock-digital').cID);
        document.querySelector('clock-digital').method();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my `clock.js`:

```js
customElements.define('clock-digital', class extends HTMLElement {

    get cID() {}

    set cID(value) {}

    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
        });
        var that = shadowRoot;
        this.cID = setInterval(function () {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            that.innerHTML = `<div style="display: inline; background-color: whitesmoke; font-style: italic;">${currentdate.getHours()}:${currentdate.getMinutes()}:${currentdate.getSeconds()}</div>`;
        }, 500);
    }

    method() {
        console.log('method');
    }

});
```

The browser console shows this error:

> ```
> undefined
>
> (index):14 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).method is not a function
> at (index):14
> ```

Why can't my inline script access `cID` and `method()`?

Comment: does it still happen if you assign the selection to a variable and then call the methods on that? Something like `var clock = document.querySelector('clock-digital'); clock.method();`

Comment: Thank you I must remove async also

Answer (score 1):

Your inline script runs **before** `clock.js` is imported (which is asynchronous because of the `async` attribute you've added to the `<script>` tag). Since the element is defined in `clock.js`, `<clock-digital>.method` and `<clock-digital>.cID` don't yet exist when your inline script tries to access them.

A couple options:

- Remove the `async` tag so that the import happens synchronously before your inline script runs ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgM7NVRFdHi5xu6m7K28?p=preview)). You'd lose the advantage of the asynchronous load, but that might not be an issue for you.
- Run your inline script after a timeout (allowing `clock.js` to finish importing)

Comment: It's work if I remove async and if I write var clock = document.querySelector('clock-digital'); clock.method();

Comment: The `async` tag is your root problem. In the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgM7NVRFdHi5xu6m7K28?p=preview), you could see that only removing `async` allows your original code to work as intended. Not caching `clock` isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the script asynchronous (`async`), which is sometimes better, you can add an `onload` event handler to the `<script>` element, that will call your inline script:

```
<script>
  function init() {
      console.log(document.querySelector('clock-digital').cID);
      document.querySelector('clock-digital').method();  
  }
</script>

<script src="clock.js" async onload="init()"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The web components API has you covered here. Simply use the [`customElements.whenDefined(tagName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined) [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here:

```js
customElements.whenDefined('clock-digital').then(() => {
    console.log(document.querySelector('clock-digital').cID);
    document.querySelector('clock-digital').method();  
});
```